# Cannot setup VestaCP in fresh CentOS8. Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'vesta'

Tags: vesta, centos8

I am trying to install vestacp on CentOS 8 fresh install. Like I said, it's fresh install with only a yum update. I am trying to setup VestaCP on it, but the install always failes on the following error.

```
Installation will take about 15 minutes...

Vesta - cmmnt
Error: Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'vesta'
Error: yum update failed
```

File: **/etc/yum.repos.d/vesta.repo**

```
[vesta]
name=Vesta - cmmnt
baseurl=http://r.vestacp.com/cmmnt/8/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-VESTA
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because Vesta doesnt support Centos8 as of yet (2020-04-30).  From the top of the install script http://vestacp.com/pub/vst-install.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# Vesta installation wrapper
# http://vestacp.com

#
# Currently Supported Operating Systems:
#
#   RHEL 5, 6, 7
#   CentOS 5, 6, 7
#   Debian 7, 8
#   Ubuntu 12.04 - 18.04
#
```